# EE2: How-to replace existing image keeping same name

Tags: ee2

In an existing site running EE2, with the following working code to upload an image:

```
ee()->load->library('filemanager');
$uploaded_file = ee()->filemanager->upload_file($directory_id);
```

The image will appear in the EE File Manager as it should. The problem arises when we want to update this image, replacing the existing file with a new one of the same name. To do this I've tried:

```
ee()->load->model('file_model');
if (ee()->file_model->get_files_by_name($file_name, $directory_id)->num_rows() > 0) {
    ee()->file_model->delete_files_by_name($dir_id, $file_name);
}
```

Which in theory would delete the existing image and then let me upload the image again. However it doesn't appear to do anything.

Is there a way in EE2 to upload a replacement image, giving it the same name as the existing image and update the corresponding file manager record?